# Adding items to textview and scrollbar stays consistent

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an Android app.  In my app there is an activity that it has a `ListView`.  `ListView` elements changes dynamically (programmatically). But when I add a new element, listview scrolls and **I don't want it**. I want to adding elements to listview and user see new elements just when user interact with it, not automatically. I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on listview adapter.

I have an example to clear my mean:

```
ListView contains = **{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5}
```

But screen size just allow 3 of them. Suppose now `{3, 4, 5}` are in screen.

Now, we add the `'6'` element and listview automatically scrolls to top and screen shows `{4 , 5 , 6}`

I want to when I add the `'6'` element, listview don't scrolls and shows the same things **(to be consistent)** and if user interact with listview and scroll, he see `'6'` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();` after updating the list

Answer (score 0):

I am new to android too.
I tried adding elements to listview on button click, i didnt face those problems....

```
<RelativeLayout
 ...>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="133dp">
</ListView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Button btn;
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = "Clicked "+ ++counter;
                array.add(s); 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

It doesn't auto scroll to the bottom.
But if you add

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

to the listview xml then it auto scroll to the bottom when you add a new element to the listview.

I hope it helps.